# Absolute Values and Percentage Values Side by Side in Bar Chart Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I would like to count on your help for the following problem that I have been facing. I've been trying, but without success, to put absolute values and percentage values side by side. Where `53` and `47` are percentage values and would be outside the parentheses and `17` and `15` are absolute values and would be inside the parentheses. Both absolute values and percentage values are already known, therefore, there is no need for any calculation to obtain them. I leave my code here for you to see how far I managed to go. This is the error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'xytext'
```

```
x_axis = ["MJO Active","MJO Inactive"]
y_axis = [53,47]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,7))
palette = sns.color_palette(["#55a868"])
rects = sns.barplot(x_axis,y_axis, linewidth = 0, color='#55a868')

ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', pad=1)
plt.xlabel('MJO Activity', fontsize=24)
plt.xticks(rotation="horizontal", size = 20)

ax.locator_params(axis='y', integer=True)
plt.ylabel('Percentage of Events (%)', fontsize=24)
plt.yticks(size = 18)
plt.ylim(0,60)

plt.title('ONDJFMA - 1996/2014',fontsize=24)
 
ax.get_xaxis().set_label_coords(0.5,-0.10)
ax.get_yaxis().set_label_coords(-0.06,0.5)

values = [17, 15]
v = 0
for rect in rects.patches:
    rects.annotate(format(rect.get_height(), '.0f'), 
                   (rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2., 1.0*rect.get_height()), 
                   '%d(%d)' % (int(rect.get_height()), values[v]), ha = 'center', va='bottom', fontsize = 20, 
                   xytext = (0, 0), 
                   textcoords = 'offset points')
    v = v + 1

plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You may want to create a [*minimal*, *reproducible* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) stripping your code to the absolute necessary and include every thing required, i.e. all libraries and especially some toy data. And perhaps you can include a figure how it looks like now and how it should look like

Comment: @max Hello max, thank you very much for your return. I'm a beginner in this community and I'm still learning to behave correctly and according to the rules and good manners. As I will participate more effectively, I will get used to it all. In the next post I handled all the recommendations you made to me and I thank you very much for that. I take the opportunity here and if you can help me, I leave my deep thanks here.

Comment: great to here. You can just edit your post and make it more likely that people answer it

Comment: @Sr. T I edited the question more fully including the code so there was no doubt. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You were nearly there. We link bar rectangles, percentage values, and absolute values with `zip`, then use [f-string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) for the display:

```
...
values = [17, 15]

for rect, perc, vals  in zip(rects.patches, y_axis, values):    
    rects.annotate(f"{perc}% ({vals})", (rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2., rect.get_height()),
                 ha='center', va='center', fontsize=20, color='black', xytext=(0, 10),
                 textcoords='offset points')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]